# Transforming constraint of linear-fractional programming (Transformation to a linear program)

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming, non-convex-optimization, linearization

I have an linear-fractional program defined like this:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x} \quad & \frac{c^{T}x + \alpha}{d^{T}x + \beta}\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & Ax \geq b\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

However, as you can see my optimization equation, constraint is slightly different from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming

Mine uses **greater than** operator in constraint, but wikipedia's equation uses **less than** operator in constraint.

So I have a question about transforming constraints in linear fractional programming.

In wikipedia page section (**Transformation to a linear program**), it transforms original formula like below. (This equation is same as widipedia)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x} \quad & c^{T}y + \alpha t\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & Ay \leq bt\\
  &d^{T}y + \beta t = 1    \\
  &t \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

But my problem's constraint is slightly different, so I changed the first constraint ( $Ay \leq bt$ )  to ( $Ay \geq bt$ ).

Is it okay to change the first constraint ( $Ay \leq bt$ )  to ( $Ay \geq bt$ ) ?

I only changed the **lessthan** operator to **greaterthan** operator.

Or how can I change my linear-fractional program to linear program?

PS: sorry for my english.. I'm not familiar with english.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi: if you want to flip the sign then you need to multiply -1 on both sides.

Comment: Why multipling -1 on both side is meaningful? I think multipling -1 is same as original constraint. For example, changing 2x <= 5 to -2x>=-5 is same.

Comment: @new_be Change the variable: $x\to -x$. The constraint becomes $-Ax\geq b \Rightarrow Ax\leq -b$. Since $b\in \mathbb R$ the sign of b doesn't matter.

Comment: @new_be: callculus42 said it correctly and he said what I was trying to say but didn't. in short, my previous suggestion to multiply by -1 on both sides is not helpful = totally useless.

Comment: @markleeds  thank you for advices!

Comment: @callculus42 thank you for advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you have done is correct.  Both $\le$ and $\ge$ are acceptable for linear programs.